# Problemas al obtener valores de un foreach LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Ingreso para personajes: Personaje1,Personaje2

```
$personajes = explode(',',$character);
$result = array();

          if (count($personajes)>1) {
//count(personajes) = 2 
            foreach ($personajes as $persona) {

                $obt_id = Tag::where('name', $persona)->get();

                foreach ($obt_id as $id) {
                    //obtengo los id de los personajes
                    echo $id->id;

                    $result[] = FileTags::with('file')->where('tag_id', $id->id)->get();
                }
            }

          }
```

El problema cuando hago echo solo me devuelve un solo id en lugar de 2 (1 por cada personaje), por lo tanto mis resultados solo son los de un personaje.
Necesito poder obtener los resultado de ambos personajes.

**EDIT:**
Para explicarme un poco mejor en este result, traigo todo los filetag que tengan el tag_id 1 y 2, como estoy usando with traigo los datos de los archivos también.

Entonces de mi tabla obtendría solo los archivos 2, 3 y 4.

```
|tabla filetags|
|  id  | tag_id | file_id |
|  1   |   1    |    2    |
|  2   |   1    |    3    |
|  3   |   2    |    4    |
|  4   |   3    |    1    |

$result = FileTags::with('file')->where('tag_id', $id->id)->get();
```

Modelo TAG

```
 public function fileTag(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\FileTags');
    }
```

Modelo Archive

```
protected $table = 'files';

public function fileTag(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\FileTags');
    }
```

Mi Modelo FileTags

```
  public function tag(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag' , 'tag_id');
    }

    public function file(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Archive', 'file_id');
    }
```

**Complemento el EDIT:**

```
    |table tag|
    | id  |   name      |
    |  1  |  Personaje1 |
    |  2  |  Personaje2 |
```

Deberia obtener el id del Personaje1 y Personaje2 es decir 1 y 2, pero solo estoy obteniendo el id del personaje 1.

Comment: ¿para qué es el segundo foreach? `foreach ($obt_id as $id) {`

Comment: Bueno en realidad no se si estara bien, pero lo uso para obtener los id de los personajes y en este caso solo se esta recuperando el id del primero

Comment: Creería que no es necesario, ya estás haciendo las iteraciones con el primer foreach, para obtener cada id luego harías simplemente `$obt_id->id`

Comment: Si lo intente pero me da el siguiente error
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id y si hago esto echo $obt_id[0]->id;  me pinta el id, pero cuando lo mando a la vista me sale esto Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Lo que pasa es que `get()` genera una colección de registros, si es un solo registro, puedes usar `first()`.

Comment: poniendo first() y enviando echo me sale el id, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema de antes al mandarlo a la vista...
$result = FileTags::with('file')->where('tag_id', $obt_id->id)->get();
Me da este error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: No, aun no lo he probado, pero el problema que tengo es que solo estoy obteniendo un solo ID, en lugar de los 2 que debería capturar. Me explico mejor en el EDIT

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: Creo que estamos un poco confundidos, así que empieza a descartar fuentes del problema: comenta la consulta que haces a Filetags, obtienes los 2 id en el foreach? De ser así el problema está en la consulta.

Comment: Pues no, no estoy los 2 id, como mencione anteriormente solo obtengo 1 T-T, lo mas raro es que antes si obtenia los 2, pero magicamente ahora obtiene 1...

Comment: Si usas este código deberían aparecer los dos id: `foreach ($personajes as $persona) {$obt_id = Tag::where('name', $persona)->first();echo $obt_id->id;}`

Comment: Si ya me esta funcionando esa parte ahora, el problema es al mostrarlos en la vista...

Comment: Ya lo logre solucionar muchas gracias por intentar ayudame :) , estaba haciendo un solo foreach, pero en realidad tenia que hacer 2 foreach para poder recorrer todo el resultado. Muchas gracias Shaz!!

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios asuntos que no funcionan muy bien según el caso y la documentación Laravel.

Los modelos cuya relación es `hasMany` deberían estar en plural a la hora de definirlos:

```
public function fileTags(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\FileTags');
}
```

Teniendo en cuenta que se busca obtener solo un id, deberíamos usar el método `first()` en vez de `get()`, pues este último nos datá una colección (array):

```
$obt_id = Tag::where('name', $persona)->first();
```

Si obtuvimos un único id (`$obt_id`), entonces no necesitamos el segundo foreach:

```
// foreach ($obt_id as $id) {

     // echo $id->id;


     // esto nos dará una colección
     $result[] = FileTags::with('file')->where('tag_id', $obt_id->id)->get();
// }
```

En la vista, será necesario usar foreach para obtener cada elemento en `$result` y otro foreach para obtener cada elemento del resultado del query a `Filetags`:

```
@foreach ($result as $filetagArray)

    @foreach ($filetagArray as $fileTag)

        {{ $fileTag->file->name }} 

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

---

Al parecer estás haciendo una relación ManyToMany, para lo cual existen métodos más sencillos, para eso puedes mirar en la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Bueno en realidad solo quite el segundo `foreach` y agregue el `$result=array();`

Comment: A partir de PHP 5.4 puedes inicializar los arrays con `[]`.